# Using functions as a service in Symfony2/3 dependency injection container

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm using Symfony2 and want to use functions as services/factories in the Symfony2/3 Dependency Injection Container. Is this possible? If not supported by default, is it possible to extend the DIC to allow this?

Two scenarios:

- using a "factory" function to create a function
- using a "factory" function to create an object

Example config:

```
# example service definition
services:
    service_a:
        function: MyNamespace\createGrobulator
        arguments:
            - "@logger"
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"

    service_b:
        function: MyNamespace\createTitulator
        arguments:
            - "@service_a"
```

and example implementations:

```
function createGrobulator(LoggerInterface $logger, $em)
{
    // do something here
    return function ($x) use ($logger, $em) {
        return something;
    };
}

function createTitulator($serviceA) {
    return new ObjectOfSomeType($serviceA);
}
```

It is possible to simulate this using a class with an `__invoke()` method but it feels very verbose, as though an unnecessary adherence to OOP, and if you use PSR recommendations you end up having lots of files for the sake of (sometimes) very small functions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can do it by using `calls` like below:

in your services.yml

```
services:
   service_a:
       function: MyNamespace\createGrobulator
       arguments:
          - "@logger"
          - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
       calls:
          - [setMyService, ['@my.service']]
```

and in your service:

```
protected $myService;

public function setMyService(MyService $myService) {
    $this->myService = $myService;
}

public function getMyService() {
    return $this->myService;
}

function createTitulator() {
    return new ObjectOfSomeType($this->getMyService());
}
```

I just made an example for you, for more information please check [Service Method Calls and Setter Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html)

Comment: Pretty sure they want to avoid the use of classes completely.

Comment: @Cerad yes if possible